# Javascript getElementById in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I'm facing a problem while printing some image based on a condition. For that reason I've used a for loop and inside it the getElementById. But the problem is it only takes that last one.

I want to print five times based on the array condition.

Here is the sample code

```js
var arr = ["false", "false", "true", "false", "true"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log("Hello")
  if (arr[i] === "true") {

    console.log("true")
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "green.png";
  } else
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "red.png";
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div>
          <img id="imageId" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <span>server1</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You are overwritting src 5 times?

Comment: It only takes the last value because that's the last value you set when looping through the array. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, you may need to create `img` elements dynamically. Please see the below code.

```js
var arr = ["false", "false", "true", "false", "true"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log("Hello");
  var img= document.createElement('img');
  if (arr[i] === "true") {
    console.log("true");    
    img.src = "green.png";
  } else
    img.src = "red.png";
  document.getElementById("imageId").appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div>
        <div id="imageId"></div>
        </div>
        <span>server1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @asmmorshed Glad it helped you. Please accept as answer if you don't mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one image, and you change the `src` of this image five times.

The `src` of the image will always be the one based on the **last** element in your array.

If you want to display all 5 images, you can't use a single `image` element, you have to use at least 5. Keep in mind, all of them requires a unique id in this case.

Or, you can use multiple image elements with the same class. Or you can create images for every element in your array.

The choice is yours, the important thing is **one image can only display one picture at a time**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative information.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs five times. Each time it manipulates the src attribute of the same `<img>` tag.

1. On the first run the src will be set to "red.png"
2. Same for the second run
3. Within the third run the same attribute will be overwritten with "green.png".
4. Now it will be set to "red.png"
5. It will be set to "green.png". So finally it will be "green.png"

If you want to manipulate more than one `<img>` tag in a loop use a array of the tag ids, create them dynamically or just name them with the incremental variable (my dirty, fast solution).

```js
  var arr = [false, false, true, false, true];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    if (arr[i]) {
      document.getElementById("imageId" + i).src = "green.png";
      document.getElementById("imageId" + i).alt = "green.png";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("imageId" + i).src = "red.png";
      document.getElementById("imageId" + i).alt = "red.png";
    }
  }
```

```html
<img id="imageId0" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<img id="imageId1" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<img id="imageId2" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<img id="imageId3" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<img id="imageId4" src="" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. It helped to understand how to think.